# Can I turn off Bloom one just one object?

Tags: light, shadows

I am trying to animate a "blood moon eclipse" and have been trying to get the moon to glow. It looks good with bloom in eevee, but the problem I ran into is that the "earth" between the "sun" and the moon also glows, and it is ruining the shadows on the moon.
I am a complete beginner and don't know what to search for or the right terms so I'm hoping someone can guide me in the right direction! Thanks!

[image: Here it is with bloom enabled]

[image: here it is with bloom disabled]

Comment: Try playing with the threshold.

Comment: ...  but Threshold will make effect only if Earth would be something daker than white (if the white sphere in you r scrren in Earth :)